# Скроллинг по секциям

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullpage

Есть сайт на котором должен быть скролл по секциям, наподобие вертикального слайдера
и если контент в секции больше высоты экрана он должен проскролится как обычный скролл.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вот плагин есть для этого: [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/)

Comment: На данный момент я его и использую. Есть проблемы с анимациями uikit которые должны работать тогда когда этот элемент находится в окне просмотра